# Iterating over DOM Objects being returned by Java methods in XSLT

Tags: saxon

We have been using Xalan for XSL transformations for quite a while and recently moved over to Saxon for XSL transformation Version 1.0 (Backward Compatibility mode).  I am calling a Java Method from XSL which returns a document object and iterating over the document object for further transformations . The transformations are proper in case of Xalan whereas I am unable to achieve the same in case of Saxon. Please let me know how to achieve the same while working with Saxon XSLT parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have raised the same question in a direct support request to Saxonica and we are trying to help you via that channel.

Comment: thanks a lot @michael . The support was helpful finally achieved the requirement as per your suggestions :)